# after window.print = "" how can I use javascript to print?

Tags: javascript

After window.print = "" how can I use javascript to print?

I just want the window.print() can work in Google Script

Comment: Why are you overwriting the print method in the first place?

Comment: unclear what you are asking, are you trying to print a page, print specific text, or getting errors when trying to print a page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get it out of `window`'s constructor:

```
window.constructor.prototype.print.call(window);
```

Comment: wow..seen this for the first time..can you please explaing what is happening here.I thought chaining could only be done in jquery.

Comment: @VAGABOND: I'm not really sure what to explain. `window`'s constructor's prototype has a reference to `print`, so you can just pull it out of there and call it with `window` as the context.

Comment: @VAGABOND that is not a "chain", that is just accessing the property of each member variable of the each previous object. for instance `constructor` is a member of window, prototype is a member of constructor so on and so fourth. In chaining the same object is returned by the each function so the next function can be used on the same object as the previous one.

Comment: @PatrickEvans:I am always 50-50 wen it comes to const and proto,thought of posting a question finally.have a look if possible.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18298435/prototype-and-constructor-in-plain-english#18298458